# "No method error" from tests in Rails using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a simple test written using RSpec and Capybara.

My failing spec is **sign_in_feature_spec.rb:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'the signin process', :type => :feature do
  it 'signs me in' do
    admin_user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
    login_as(admin_user, :scope => :admin_user)
    visit root_path
    puts page.body
  end
end
```

When I run this spec, I see next report:

> 1 example, 0 failures, 1 passed

So, the test was successful, but I get this output from `puts page.body`:

````
NoMethodError at /
==================

> undefined method `saved_filters' for #<AdminUser:0x00000009abf870>

activemodel (4.1.9) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb, line 435
-------------------------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
  430       def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  431         if respond_to_without_attributes?(method, true)
  432           super
  433         else
  434           match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
> 435           match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
  436         end
  437       end
  438   
  439       # +attribute_missing+ is like +method_missing+, but for attributes. When
  440       # +method_missing+ is called we check to see if there is a matching
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - activemodel (4.1.9) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:213:in `method_missing'
 - lib/active_admin/filter_saver/controller.rb:35:in `save_filters?'
 - config/initializers/active_admin.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `block in make_lambda'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
 - config/initializers/instrumentation_notification.rb:28:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 - config/initializers/instrumentation_notification.rb:27:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
 - actionview (4.1.9) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:685:in `call'
 - warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 - warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:562:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 - request_store (1.1.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
 - rack-test (0.6.3) lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
 - rack-test (0.6.3) lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
 - rack-test (0.6.3) lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:60:in `process'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:35:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:21:in `visit'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:42:in `visit'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/session.rb:232:in `visit'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 - rspec-rails (3.2.0) lib/rspec/rails/example/feature_example_group.rb:28:in `visit'
 - spec/features/sign_in_feature_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `block in run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `block in run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
 - rspec-rails (3.2.0) lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387:in `execute_with'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:617:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:548:in `block in run_examples'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `run_examples'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `block in run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 - ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'

Full backtrace
--------------

 - activemodel (4.1.9) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:213:in `method_missing'
 - lib/active_admin/filter_saver/controller.rb:35:in `save_filters?'
 - config/initializers/active_admin.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `block in make_lambda'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:143:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
 - config/initializers/instrumentation_notification.rb:28:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
 - config/initializers/instrumentation_notification.rb:27:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
 - actionview (4.1.9) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:685:in `call'
 - warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 - warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:562:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 - request_store (1.1.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 - activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
 - railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:65:in `block in call'
 - rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
 - rack-test (0.6.3) lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
 - rack-test (0.6.3) lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
 - rack-test (0.6.3) lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
 - /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/forwardable.rb:183:in `get'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:60:in `process'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:35:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:21:in `visit'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:42:in `visit'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/session.rb:232:in `visit'
 - capybara (2.5.0) lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 - rspec-rails (3.2.0) lib/rspec/rails/example/feature_example_group.rb:28:in `visit'
 - spec/features/sign_in_feature_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:177:in `block in run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `block in run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
 - rspec-rails (3.2.0) lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387:in `execute_with'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:617:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:548:in `block in run_examples'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `run_examples'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `block in run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
 - rspec-core (3.2.0) exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
 - ruby/2.1.0/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'
 - -e:1:in `<main>'
````

What can cause this backtrace? Is there some problem with the test environment configuration? When I switched to `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'development'` the problem persists, but if I run the application in development all is OK and after auth I see the correct page.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is going on here without more information. I'm guessing you probably need to include the activeadmin module in your spec, based on the fact that the error is coming from lib/active_admin.

Comment: It looks like you've implemented filter saving for active_admin but your AdminUser class doesn't actually have support for them (no #saved_filters method on the AdminUser class) - post your AdminUser class definition and the FactoryGirl factory for it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.
After running tests, testing database was cleared, so I have no entry for user which tried to login therefore method saved_filters could not be found. When I have added this user, I have seen page of my application.